# How to fix cannot read querySelector of null in React hook when Object is not in DOM

Tags: reactjs, dom, react-hooks, jquery-selectors, react-context

components/VideoPlayer.js

```
import '../../style/VideoPlayer/VideoPlayer.css';
const VideoPlayer = () => {...some code...return(...some code...)} export default VideoPlayer
```

VideoContainer.js

```
import VideoPlayer from "../../VideoPlayer"
import useVideoPlayer from "../../../hooks/useVideoPlayer"

const VideoContainer = ({ info }) => {

const { playPause, toggleFullScreen, fullscreen } = useVideoPlayer()
return (
<React.Fragment>
<div>
...
{/* {playPause == true ? (
            <div><VideoPlayer/></div>)
            : null} */}

{fullscreen && <div id="testing"><VideoPlayer src={info.somesrc} title={info.sometitle} /></div>}

{/* <div id="testing"><VideoPlayer src={info.somesrc} title={info.sometitle} /></div> */}
...
</div>
</React.Fragment>
)
```

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useLayoutEffect } from 'react'
const useVideoPlayer = () => {
    const [playVideo, setPlayVideo] = useState(false)
    const [fullscreen, setFullscreen] = useState(false)

    useEffect(() => {
    const controlsContainer = document.querySelector('.video-container .controls-container');
    const playPauseButton = document.querySelector('.video-container .controls button.play-pause');
    const pauseButton = playPauseButton.querySelector('.paused'); // typeError cannot read property querySelector of null
    ...some other queryselectors...
    }, []);

const displayControls = () => {
    let controlsTimeout;
    const controlsContainer = document.querySelector('.video-container .controls-container');
    ...
}

const playPause= () => {
  const video = document.querySelector('.video-container video');
  if (...) {
    video.play(); 
    setPlayVideo(true);
  } else (...) {
    video.pause();
    setPlayVideo(false);
  };
}

const toggleFullScreen = () => {
 const videoContainer = document.querySelector('.video-container');
 if (...) {setFullscreen(true)} else (...) {setFullscreen(false)};
}

...
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', () => {
...
}

const video = document.querySelector('.video-container video');

video && (video.addEventListener('timeupdate', () => {
...
}

...a dozen other addEventListeners for different elements fetched by querySelectors...

return { playPause, toggleFullScreen, fullscreen }

}

export default useVideoPlayer;
```

I am passing back the `playPause`, `toggleFullscreen` functions and a `fullscreen` reactcontext from the `useVideoPlayer` hook to the react container.
I use `&&` and check if `fullscreen` is true or false to render `<VideoPlayer/>` or not

The `useVideoPlayer` hook doesnt work when the component is not in the DOM, how do I fix that?

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'querySelector' of null
    at eval (useVideoPlayer.js:41)
    at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:19731)
    at commitPassiveHookEffects (react-dom.development.js:19769)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:188)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:237)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:292)
    at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:22853)
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:653)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11039)
    at flushPassiveEffects (react-dom.development.js:22820)
```

I have tried `useLayoutEffect`, passing `useRef(null)` and wrapping in `if (containerRef.current) {}` but it makes no difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check that the element exists before trying to use it:

```
const pauseButton = playPauseButton && playPauseButton.querySelector('.paused');
```

If you want something more scalable, you could explicitly control whether it's rendered or not in your `VideoContainer` and then pass that in to your hook:

```
const VideoContainer = ({ info }) => {
    const [mounted, setMounted] = useState(false)
    const { playPause, toggleFullScreen, fullscreen } = useVideoPlayer(mounted)
    return (
    ...
    {mounted ? <VideoPlayer/> : null}
```

Comment: that is quite a lot of checks. I have a dozen querySelectors which are used by a dozen other functions and addEventListeners in the React hook. Is there a shorter way to toggle that change?

Comment: I wrapped the hook with a conditional `mounted` and added `onClick={() => { mounted ? setMounted(false) : setMounted(true) }};` to its parent container. But I am still getting a `Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: playPause is not defined` because those return values are nullified

Comment: Can you add a simple demo of your use case somewhere?

Comment: can you see https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-thunder-pev51?file=/src/App.js

Comment: so maybe mounted is the wrong way to go, I think you should just be a bit more careful with checking for existence before trying to access properties https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-smoke-0t1oj